# Drop down selections based on Previous selection but come empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am running an event and it is in few cities, different dates and different times.. I want the options to appear based on the previous selection but before i selected it come empty !

I have 3 cities "**City1**" "**City2**" "**City3**"

And "**City1**" is on
"**22nd July**" & "**25th July**"

And on "**22nd July**" there are 2 sessions "**2pm**" & "**5pm**"

take a look at the demo it's okay but when I try it on localhost it come empty !

```
<select id="menu1" class="menu"></select>
<select id="menu2" class="menu"></select>
```

```
var data = {
    "New York": ["July 20", "July 21"],
    "Miami": ["July 22", "July 23"],
    "San Francisco": ["July 24", "July 25"],
}

// populate menu1
for (var i in data) {
    $('#menu1').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
}

// populate menu2 based on menu1's value
$('#menu1').change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[key]) {
        $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJn8g/)

Comment: i try this on localhost but it works fine!

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed so why it come empty !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var data = {
    "New York": ["July 20", "July 21"],
    "Miami": ["July 22", "July 23"],
    "San Francisco": ["July 24", "July 25"],
}

// populate menu1
for (var i in data) {
    $('#menu1').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
}

// populate menu2 based on menu1's value
$('#menu1').change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[key]) {
        $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
    }
}).trigger('change');

});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="menu1" class="menu"></select>
  <select id="menu2" class="menu"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

If your code is working in fiddle the the above code should work.

Comment: @Joseph then something is wrong in the other part of the code.You should post your entire code

Comment: all my code containing 2 select tag and that script ? nothing else 
take a look at the demo  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eJn8g/)

Comment: @Joseph i will post the entire code.Just copy it and paste it in your page.